# Beamer note page: Increase slide size

Tags: beamer

I'm using the `beamer` class with `note` pages. In the upper right corner I see always the slide the notes are referring to. Is it possible to change the size of this preview?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}
\begin{frame}{foo}
Some text.
\end{frame}
\note{Many notes}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beamer's template `note page` (in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`) defines how are note pages constructed. The slide size in note pages is hard coded in this template. By default, notes title uses `.25\paperheight` and slide in it and slide in notes is reduced to `.25\paperheight x .25\paperwidth`.

In next code I've copied `note page`template and changed notes title and slide in notes proportions to use `.45\paperheight`. It's not an elegant solution and it reduces available space for notes. May be someone else will provide a better answer.

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{mynotes}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \usebeamerfont{note title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note title}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note title}{}{%
      \insertvrule{.45\paperheight}{note title.bg}%
      \vskip-.45\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip%
    }%
    \vbox{
      \hfill\insertslideintonotes{0.45}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin\hskip0pt%
      \vskip-0.45\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}
        \begin{pgflowlevelscope}{\pgftransformrotate{90}}
          {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-2cm}{0.2cm}}%
          \pgftext[base,left]{\usebeamerfont{note date}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note date}\the\year-\ifnum\month<10\relax0\fi\the\month-\ifnum\day<10\relax0\fi\the\day}}
        \end{pgflowlevelscope}
      \end{pgfpicture}}
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .45\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note page}{}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \insertvrule{.55\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
    \vskip-.55\paperheight%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}
\makeatother

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[mynotes]

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
   \lipsum[1]
 \end{frame}
\note[itemize]
{\item This is a note
\item A second note}

\end{document}
```

[image]