# Is it possible to see my script while presenting in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I love slides created with Beamer, and I am using it.

Yet, I also quite like that PowerPoint is able to show my script on my screen and show the slides on the projector while I am presenting.

Is it a way to achieve this with Beamer or other TeX techniques?

Comment: beamer also has `notes` but it has a few quirks that you will find out soon :)

Comment: I think the problem is not about beamer itself, but about  PDF-viewer's inability to occupy both screen. Once you get over it beamer will no longer be useful in showing you scripts.

Comment: Hmmm, if you had a double width page and clipped half to the projector and half to the screen...  pdfpages!!!

Comment: @JohnKormylo This is in fact very smart! Is there one such "double-width" Beamer class, where I make normal slides on the left, and write my script on the right?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224267/how-to-include-a-preview-of-next-slide-in-beamers-speaker-notes and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame

Comment: I'm perhaps missing something: isn't this just the concept of notes with `show notes on second screen` set (example, page 201 of manual)?

Comment: @JosephWright I find page 211 also useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For details and further options, see the manual beginning on page 211.

Here's a way to put notes on the second screen. It is important that the PDF viewer you will be using can cope with this!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    This is some text for the first slide.
    \note{Talk about putting text on the slide.}
    \note{Don't forget the text!}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Second Frame}
    This is some text for the second slide.
    \note{Explain how the second thing follows from the first.}
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Third Frame}
    This is some text for the third slide.
    \note{Use that example from the film to illustrate the point.}
    \note{Don't spend more than 5 minutes on this!}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slides with notes]

Comment: for future reference: one such viewer is pyimpress (https://pympress.xyz)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way.  You will need to replace beamer_test with you own beamer PDF.

If you don't want to overlay the scripts, just use \newpage instead of \pause.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage[display]{texpower}

\newcounter{pdfpage}
\geometry{paperwidth=10in,paperheight=3.8in,left=5.2in,top=.2in,right=.2in,bottom=.5in}
\AddEverypageHook{\stepcounter{pdfpage}
 \raisebox{-2.8in}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\hspace{-1in}%
 \includegraphics[page=\thepdfpage]{beamer_test}}}}
\parindent=0pt
\parskip=\baselineskip

\begin{document}\Large
This is the script for the first page of overlay.

\pause
This is the script for the second page of overlay.
\end{document}
```

---

[image: beamer plus script]

---

[image: second page]

OTOH, it appears I've reinvented the wheel.

Comment: I do think `beamer`'s option is a bit more straightforward... ;).

Comment: @cfr - You only think so because you haven't looked at beamer.cls

Comment: ... for the end user... ;)