# Powerpoint live presentation functionalities with LaTex beamer?

Tags: beamer, mac, presentations, powerpoint

For most presentations, I find it easier to use LaTex than Powerpoint. However, one feature I really miss with LaTex is the handful of presentation functionalities of Powerpoint. Basically, while the presentation is on full screen on a second monitor, I can see on my own screen:

- A timer of the presentation
- The current slide
- The next slide

as shown in the following picture :

[image]

Do you know of any way to emulate these functionalities with a LaTex beamer presentation? Would any pdf reader have such functionalities (**preferably on mac** and preferably **free**)?

Comment: PDF is sort of unsuitable for those requirements. Instead, check out [Reveal JS](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224267/how-to-include-a-preview-of-next-slide-in-beamers-speaker-notes

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/note-page-showing-the-next-frame

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes : yes indeed, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21777/is-there-a-nice-solution-to-get-a-presenter-mode-for-latex-presentations/21857#21857 mentionned in on of DG's links. Unfortunately missed those when I looked for an answer before posting the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

- **[Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/)**

Also:

- [PDF Presenter](http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net)
- [Skim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21857/29873)
- [Keynote](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/freesoftware/pdftokeynote.html)

Comment: Thanks. Precisely the kind of apps I was looking for. Unfortunately, PDF Presenter has lots of bugs on osx, and Impressive is Windows/Linux only, but that's a good start. Any other osx compatible solutions are welcome!

Comment: Sorry, I thought `Impressive` would run on OS X.

Comment: +1 for Présentation.app, very similar to PDFslide (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

For OSX, look at [osx-adobe-beamer](https://github.com/scottsievert/osx-adobe-beamer). It wraps Adobe Reader so it shows the notes and slides on different pages.

It has the following features

> - video/animation
> - notes for current slide
> - on notes, shows current slide
> - <s>timer (i.e., "15 minutes remaining")</s>
> - <s>next slide</s>

In your latex document include

```
\usepackage[slides]{osx-adobe-beamer}
% or 
\usepackage[notes]{osx-adobe-beamer}
```

and copy the resulting PDF so you can display both at once. Open them both in Adobe Reader and run the command

```
python /path/to/present.py
```

And you're all set! If this application fails on you during a presentation, you can still survive because it only maps your keymaps to *both* Adobe Reader windows.

*(disclaimer: I am the developer -- a quick weekend hack!)*

Comment: Saw this question bumped to the top of the active list about an hour ago and took note of it. Here I am on reddit, minding my own business, when I see a link to the project. "My, this is simply an amazing coincidence!", I think to myself. I come back here only to discover that this was the reason the post was bumped in the first place. +1 for taking on the project and +ducks for making me chuckle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Following sourceforge's links based on @DG' answer, I found :

- [PDFslide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfslide/)

It is supposedly in beta but it is much more stable than [PDF Presenter](http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net/) in osx in my (admittedly very short) experience.

It is minimal compared to [PDF Presenter](http://pdfpresenter.sourceforge.net/) but basically does what I am looking for (cf. the functionalities I list in the question).