# Beamer Note Title - How to make it look like infolines used in normal frames?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I specifically want to:

- Get rid of the document title.
- Display the section and subsection titles in the same row, center aligned.
- Retain the grey color scheme.

Here's an MWE, with screenshot of the current output attached.

(Code for note page borrowed, with modifications, from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159607)

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamerfont{note title}{size=\tiny}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{mynotes}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \usebeamerfont{note title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note title}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note title}{}{%
      \insertvrule{0.15\paperheight}{note title.bg}%
      \vskip-.15\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .15\paperheight{\vskip0.5em
      \hbox{\insertshorttitle[width=8cm]}%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsection}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip17.4pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{7.5cm}\def\breakhere{}\insertsubsection\end{minipage}}\fi%
      }%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertshortframetitle}%
      \hbox{\ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt{\hskip30.8pt\raise3pt\hbox{\vrule
            width0.4pt height7pt\vrule width 9pt
            height0.4pt}}\hskip1pt\hbox{\insertshortframetitle[width=7cm]}\fi%
      }%
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note page}{}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \insertvrule{.85\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
    \vskip-.85\paperheight%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[mynotes]

\title{Document Title}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\begin{frame}
Content goes here
\end{frame}

\note {
Notes go here
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the note page to something like this:

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamerfont{note title}{size=\tiny}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{mynotes}
{%
  {%
    \scriptsize
    \usebeamerfont{note title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{note title}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note title}{}{%
      \insertvrule{0.05\paperheight}{note title.bg}%
      \vskip-.05\paperheight%
      \nointerlineskip%
    }%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to .05\paperheight{\vfil
      \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
        \hfill\insertsection
      \end{minipage}%
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
        \insertsubsection\hfill
      \end{minipage}%      
      \vfil}%
  }%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{note page}{}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \insertvrule{.95\paperheight}{note page.bg}%
    \vskip-.95\paperheight%
  }%
  \vskip.25em
  \nointerlineskip
  \insertnote
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[mynotes]

\title{Document Title}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\subsection{Subsection Title}

\begin{frame}
Content goes here
\end{frame}

\note {
Notes go here
}

\end{document}
```

[image]